# Jenkins cannot build maven and gradle projects

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle, nfs

I have configured jenkins on kubernetes cluster as a pod with NFS volume mount. when i try to build code, using maven and gradle , i'm getting these error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No locks available
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock(FileDispatcherImpl.java:94)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1114)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1155)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:55)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. I had to update volume claim yaml. accessModes to ReadWriteOnce, previous it was ReadWriteMany.